# Can we create SOAP and REST Web Services in an single application

Tags: web-services, rest, soapui

Can we create SOAP and REST Web Services in an single application.
If "YES" then how to distinguish between them while performing testing

Comment: This is little broad. Please provide the context. If you are using request step, you would definitely know whether that is a soap or rest. So, please clarify the question in detail.

Answer (score 0):

Applications usually expose either SOAP, or REST services. However, if you have both customers who prefer REST (e.g. for simplicity) and who prefer SOAP (e.g. because it is better supported by their integration tools and standards), it might be right to provide both SOAP and REST. Of course there is a drawback of higher development and support cost, so you need to consider whether it's worthy to do both.

These services should share business logic as much as possible to avoid inconsistencies.

Regarding the testing you simply test the set of REST services and the set of SOAP services. In addition I recommend to test the REST and SOAP service for the same function and compare whether they produce the same result (in service response and within application).